# Method overloading exercise

Tags: java, overloading

I got this exercise on my exam but I can't figure out 1 solution. So I was given this:

```
public class X {
    public int f(A a, int n) {
        n = n + 1;
        return 1;
    }

    public int h(B b, int n) {
        try {
            n = n + 3;
            return f(b,n);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            return n * 4;
        }
    }
}

public class Y extends X {
    public int f(A b, int n) {
        return n + b.i();
    }

    public int f(B b, int n) {
        return 3*n - b.i();
    }
}

public class Z extends Y {
    public int f(B b, int n) {
        return f((A)b,n) + super.f(b,n);
    }
}

public class A {
    public int i() {
        return 7;
    }
}

public class B extends A {
    public int i() {
        return super.i() + 6;
    }
}

static class E extends RuntimeException {
}
```

And I needed to figure out:

```
new Z().h(new B(), 3)
```

The solution is 19 but I don't understand why the f method of class Y is used instead of the f method of class Z.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I did that but I just don't understand why the f method of Y is used instead of the f method of Z.

Comment: Or, alternatively: put exact println statements into **each** method, like "Z:f returning ..."

Comment: @DriesCoppens: Funny, I was just thinking about this question and going to come back and say "But perhaps not in this case." :-)

Comment: The other thing that might help: start putting @Override on those methods that you think override something. Just to be sure that there aren't subtle "drifts" between "assumed polymorphism" ... and reality being different.

Comment: And just for the record: the **true** lesson from this exercise is: **never ever** write such code ;-)

Comment: Indeed why would anyone ever write such code even for an exercice. (professors) :-) @GhostCat

Comment: @DriesCoppens The exercise point is clear. It touches many concepts, such as polymorphism (shadowing vs overriding) and call-by-value and so on. So there is a lot to be learned from; and it might take some time to write up some code. The other lesson here: don't try to answer a question that TJ Crowder already has his fingers - you will be too late any way; and when you are about to post your answer, TJ will already have an accepted one in place.

Comment: @GhostCat You are right... (38 seconds later) :)

Comment: @GhostCat: LOL. David's answer is good, though, I'm glad he did post it.

Comment: the Z class overrides only one of the overloaded f methods in Y.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The signature of the method being called is determined at compilation time, not runtime. The call to `f` is in `X`'s `h`:

```
return f(b,n);
```

If you look at `X`, the only `f` it can call is its `f(A, int)`. It doesn't have access to an `f(B, int)`. So it's compiled with a call to `f(A, int)`. `Y` overrides `f(A, int)` and `Z` does not, and so anything that's a `Y` instance (including `Z` instances) will use `Y`'s version of `f(A, int)`. So `Y`'s `f(A, int)` is used.

Answer (score 3):

It is not simple, but you must see the class X

```
public class X {
    public int f(A a, int n) {
        n = n + 1;
        return 1;
    }

    public int h(B b, int n) {
        try {
            n = n + 3;
            return f(b,n); // <- at this point
        } catch(Exception e) {
            return n * 4;
        }
    }
}
```

The only method defined is `f(A a, int n)` for this, It'll invoke it (or overrided method with this signature). That It's:

```
public class Y extends X {
    public int f(A b, int n) {
         return n + b.i();
    }
}
```

Z class doesn't override `public int f(A a, int n)`.